# Accesing broadcast events in C#

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I have created the EA adding in C# which contains the menus now `EA_MenuClick` is called when the menu item is clicked i want to show the windows form. So this is working only if the model file is opened. If the model file is not opened it throws a message as "object reference not set to an instance of an object".

So how can I display form even if no model file is opened?  After research I found that we can control through file open broadcast so how can I access this method in C# and modify it.

In the refrence I have added Interop EA.dll so which other Reference should I add to get EA_Fileopen function
Thanks

Comment: How would you show, say, Word menus if Word is not open?

Comment: You must be doing wrong, because you can use the `EA_MenuClick` event without the need to have a model open.
Debug your code in order to figure out why you get a nullpointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

Interop.EA contains the whole EA API, there's no additional reference to be added.

The reason you are getting the error is that you are trying to access the contents of the repository without first checking that a repository is open. You need to check that the `Repository` parameter of `EA_MenuClick()` is valid.

You should also add a menu state handler (`EA_GetMenuState()`) which checks if the repository is valid and sets `IsEnabled` to false for all menu items which require an open repository. This will disable them and prevent EA from calling `EA_MenuClick()`.